# PersistenceUnitLoadingException from EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

i have already developed a jpa example but it is fine 
but i am getting the error when running another example with jpa                         one errors are given below

```
on [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7
Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [testjpa] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7212] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [updatedTime] from the entity class [class entity.Product] does not specify a temporal type. A temporal type must be specified for persistent fields or properties of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:65)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
        at test.SurveyTest.main(SurveyTest.java:21)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [testjpa] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7212] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [updatedTime] from the entity class [class entity.Product] does not specify a temporal type. A temporal type must be specified for persistent fields or properties of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:991)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:124)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [testjpa] failed.
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7212] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [updatedTime] from the entity class [class entity.Product] does not specify a temporal type. A temporal type must be specified for persistent fields or properties of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:210)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7212] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.2.v20100323-r6872): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [updatedTime] from the entity class [class entity.Product] does not specify a temporal type. A temporal type must be specified for persistent fields or properties of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.noTemporalTypeSpecified(ValidationException.java:1395)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processTemporal(MappingAccessor.java:1590)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processJPAConverters(MappingAccessor.java:1358)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1422)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingValueConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1440)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.BasicAccessor.process(BasicAccessor.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataDescriptor.processAccessors(MetadataDescriptor.java:1287)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.processAccessors(ClassAccessor.java:825)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processAccessors(EntityAccessor.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.process(EntityAccessor.java:708)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage2(MetadataProject.java:1333)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:461)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:945)
        ... 6 more
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 12):

> Exception Description: The attribute [updatedTime] from the entity class [class entity.Product] does not specify a temporal type. A temporal type must be specified for persistent fields or properties of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.

You have to annotate that field with @Temporal: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Temporal.html

to specify if it's a DATE, TIME or TIMESTAMP.